# Подскажите как правильно разместить функцию QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames внутри оператора try в C++

Tags: исключения, c++11, try-catch

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему происходит аварийное завершение программы, если внутри оператра помещена только функция QStringList fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames.... Я хотел оставить внутри try только присваивание значений имен файлов fileName, а остальное выполнить после оператора try.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()  // open_file
{
    QStringList fileName;
    try {
        QStringList fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open Files"), QDir::currentPath(), tr("Audio Files: *.mp3, *.flac, *.wav,"
                                                                                                            " *.ape, *.aac, *.ac3, *.dff, *.dts,"
                                                                                                            " *.ogg, *.m4a, *.mkv, *.iso (*.mp3"
                                                                                                            " *.flac *.wav *.ape *.aac *.ac3 *.dff"
                                                                                                            " *.dts *.ogg *.m4a *.mkv *.iso);;All files (*.*)"));



    }  catch (...) {
        g_message = "One of files cannot be opened.";
        Taskcomplete taskcomplete;
        taskcomplete.setModal(true);
        taskcomplete.exec();
        return;
    };
    
    if (fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    } else {
        QString file_name = fileName.at(0);
        std::string file_0 = file_name.toUtf8().constData();
        std::cout << "" << file_0 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Если же внутри оператора try поместить другие операторы, которые работают с полученным значением fileName, то программа работает корректно. Вот работающий код:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()  // open_file
{
    try {
        QStringList fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open Files"), QDir::currentPath(), tr("Audio Files: *.mp3, *.flac, *.wav,"
                                                                                                            " *.ape, *.aac, *.ac3, *.dff, *.dts,"
                                                                                                            " *.ogg, *.m4a, *.mkv, *.iso (*.mp3"
                                                                                                            " *.flac *.wav *.ape *.aac *.ac3 *.dff"
                                                                                                            " *.dts *.ogg *.m4a *.mkv *.iso);;All files (*.*)"));

        if (fileName.isEmpty())
        {
            return;

        } else {
            QString file_name = fileName.at(0);
            std::string file_0 = file_name.toUtf8().constData();
            std::cout << "" << file_0 << std::endl;
        }

    }  catch (...) {
        g_message = "One of files cannot be opened.";
        Taskcomplete taskcomplete;
        taskcomplete.setModal(true);
        taskcomplete.exec();
        return;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто вы учудили немного...

```
 QStringList fileName;
 try {
    QStringList fileName = ...
```

Что мы видим? **Вне** блока `try` объявлена неинициализированная переменная `fileName`. Затем **в** блоке `try` объявлена **другая** переменная `fileName`, инициализирована. По выходе из блока она прекращает свою жизнедеятельность, и вы продолжаете работать с первой, *неинициализированной* переменной.

Все понятно? И понятно, что делать?..

Comment: После try убрал QStringList и всё заработало. Спасибо!